# Ubuntu. Linux (лаги вирутальной машины)

Tags: ubuntu

Развернул на VB вирутуалку на ubuntu, хотел софт нормально перенести с винды на линукс. В итоге Pycharm и Dbeaver лагают. Можно ли что-то сделать с самой виртуалкой чтобы лагало меньше?

Comment: виртуалка в плане CPU он основной машины сильно отличаться не должна (я давно как-то проверял и меня в тестах CPU разница был 5-10%), если лагает, то может это у вас UI рендерится на проце, а не видеокарте? может стоит попробовать поставить virtualbox guest extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Господа, все продукты JetBrains - построены на одном ядре, и весьма требовательны к производительности компа. То есть, проц "последнего поколения из Интелов" и 32 гига оперативки при работе с ними - это норма. На маках с M1 будет шевелиться чуть быстрее, но все равно - чувствуется, что там "под капотом" среда разработки делает всякие могучие вещи.

Что делаете Вы?

Вы берете этот софт, который "не знаю, что там, но память оно любит" и засовываете его в виртуалочку. Которая и сама потребляет часть мощности процессора, и, кроме того, обладает своим мнением о том, что выгрузить на диск, а что подержать в памяти.

А еще там Винда есть, а она занимается своими *важными делами*. И на это ей тоже нужны процессор и память.

И после этого Вы удивляетесь, что "всё немного тормозит"?

В общем, можно, конечно, выделить виртуалке побольше ресурсов, но работать так Вы, скорее всего, не сможете. (ну, или это будет дзенское упражнение на развитие терпения)

Хотите "нормально перенести" - ставьте линукс, например, на отдельный диск, на голое максимально производительное железо, и пробуйте на нём всё настроить.

Comment: Спасибо, понял! Думаю ubuntu как основную OC поставить. Особо на ПК ничего такого не делаю, что требовало бы именно ОС винды.